# UIWebView going blank when navigating back to the view

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app that loads a UIWebView. And that works well. It is possible for the user to click a link in the web view which then creates a new view controller/web view to load the link, which also works well.

What isn't working so well, is that sometimes (1/4 maybe) when I come back to the initial web view, the view is blank white.

The controller is not being dealloced, and is not receiving memory warning in between. And I'm totally puzzled.

Anyone know what's going on, and more especially, how to fix it?

Here are any methods that have anything to do with the controllers:

Initial Controller:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        WebView * wv = [[WebView alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebView" bundle:nil];
        UIBarButtonItem *backBar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back to the Article" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBar;
        [backBar release];
        [[UIAppDelegate navigationController] pushViewController:wv animated:YES];
        [[wv webView] loadRequest:request];
        [wv release];
    }
    return NO;
}
else
    return YES;
}
```

Other controller (WebView):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [webView setDelegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's not receiving a memory warning?

It might not be obvious when this occurs.

Comment: I think that this was the case.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that I resolved by using:

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:@"HTML GOES HERE" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

instead of:

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:@"HTML GOES HERE" baseURL:nil];
```

Apparently the UIWebView was clearing as soon as

```
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:myModalViewController animated:YES];
```

was called when passing nil for the baseURL: argument of UIWebView's -loadHTMLString:baseURL: method.  This bug appeared after upgrading to the iOS 4.3 SDK.